# How to extract Excel sheets into multiple CSVs then transform into .txt file on Oracle Data Integrator (ODI)?

Tags: python, excel, oracle-data-integrator

I'm seeking experts' help to suggest/recommend a better workaround to my use case below, (ODI is very new to me btw):

- **Desired output**: .txt files
- **Input**: an excel file with multiple sheets
- **Input source**: FTP server
- **Environment to use**: ODI

I have an Excel file and I will need to extract the sheets into separate CSVs. I managed to do this using a short python scripts.

My idea is to: ODI connect to the FTP > ODI run the python script > ODI read the CSVs and insert into MySQL db > MySQL export tables into .txt files.

Answer (score 1):

From What you have mentioned , they seemed to be the minimum steps you have to go through to achieve your outcome.
None of them can be skipped.

- Using `OdiOSCommand` you can run your script, which will convert your
  sheet to csv.
- Then you have to `reverse engineer, map to target.
- Query script will used to write to a .txt file, run this under `procedure` . All of them under single
  package.